# Python - Huffman bit compression

Tags: python, list, nodes

I need help on this. I made a Huffman compression program. For example I'll input "google", I can just print it like this:

```
Character | Frequency | Huffman Code
------------------------------------
'g'       |         2 |           0
'o'       |         2 |          11
'l'       |         1 |         101
'e'       |         1 |         100
```

I also need to print the combined bits so if I use that it will be:

```
011101100
```

Which is wrong because as far as I understand Huffman compression it should be:

```
011110101100
```

So my output should be:

```
Character | Frequency | Huffman Code
------------------------------------
'g'       |         2 |           0
'o'       |         2 |          11
'o'       |         2 |          11
'g'       |         2 |           0
'l'       |         1 |         101
'e'       |         1 |         100
```

Basically I need to display it based on what I input. So if I input "test" it should also print test vertically with their corresponding bits since I'm just appending the bits and displaying them. How do I achieve this? Here's the printing part:

```
freq = {}
for c in word:
    if c in freq:
        freq[c] += 1
    else:
        freq[c] = 1

freq = sorted(freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

if check:
    print (" Char | Freq ")
    for key, c in freq:
        print (" %4r | %d" % (key, c))

nodes = freq

while len(nodes) > 1:
    key1, c1 = nodes[-1]
    key2, c2 = nodes[-2]
    nodes = nodes[:-2]
    node = NodeTree(key1, key2)
    nodes.append((node, c1 + c2))
    nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

if check:
    print ("left: %s" % nodes[0][0].nodes()[0])
    print ("right: %s" % nodes[0][0].nodes()[1])

huffmanCode = huffman(nodes[0][0])

print ("\n")
print (" Character | Frequency  | Huffman code ")
print ("---------------------------------------")

for char, frequency in freq:
   print (" %-9r | %10d | %12s" % (char, frequency, huffmanCode[char]))
```

P.S. I know I shouldn't be sorting them I'll remove the sorting part don't worry